# Timer code compiling but not working correctly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, timer, android-context

New to Android.

I am trying to create an application to play a beep at intervals. There is a simple play button on the screen which calls the readyToBeep function which calls Beep.class. I don't get an error, it compiles and runs. But I don't hear the MP3 sound. The activity id called and the layout is changed to buzz.xml, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong because I am not getting any error messages. Any indications on what the problem is??

TIA

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.timer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void readyToBeep(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Beep.class);
        startActivity(intent);  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Beep.java

```
package com.example.timer;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Beep extends Activity  {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buzz); 
     new Beep();
} 

    private Context Context;
    Timer timer;

    public Beep(){};

    public Beep(Context Context) {

        this.Context = Context;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(),
                       1500,        //initial delay
                       1*1500);  //subsequent rate
        }

        class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

            public void run() {

                MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Context, R.raw.beep);  
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mPlayer.start();

            }
        }
    }
```

Now working Beep.java(Credit to MagicCode)

```
package com.example.timer;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class Beep extends Activity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buzz); 

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(),
               1500,        //initial delay
               1*1500);  //subsequent rate
    }

         Timer timer;

 public Beep(){};



     class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

                    public void run() {

                MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beep);  
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mPlayer.start();

            }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This never runs

```
public final void main() {

setContentView(R.layout.buzz); 
     new Beep();
}
```

This is Android so you need to override `onCreate()` as you are doing in the first `Activity`. Try

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buzz); 
     new Beep();
}
```

Comment: No luck, I tried that already but it didn't work, i'll update the code to include the onCreate method instead. As an aside I'm just wondering how it knows to change the layout if the main function never runs?

Comment: That's what `setContentView()` inside of `onCreate()` is for

Comment: This `new Beep();` does nothing since its an `Activity`. You don't want to instantiate an `Activity` that way